# How to add a side borders for unseleted tabs in tabBar flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, tabbar

I want to give a border for unselected tabs as displayed in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code with minor modifications.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          bottom: TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.blue),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("APPS"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("MOVIES"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("GAMES"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          Icon(Icons.apps),
          Icon(Icons.movie),
          Icon(Icons.games),
        ]),
      ));
  }
}
```

For more styling https://mightytechno.com/style-tabs-in-flutter-app/